# How to create tabs dynamically in extjs?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I am new to extjs. I want to create tabs in my panel, based on a number generated from dataBase (consider the value is stored in 'numOfTabs' which is fetched from dataBase and available in JS).

I don't want to use any button event to generate tabs, but on page load itself I need to view tabs.

How can I create 'n' tabs in my panel, where 'n' is the value in numOfTabs ?

Using extjs4.2.2

Comment: See: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.4/extjs-build/examples/tabs/tabs-adv.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from the below link

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.4/extjs-build/examples/tabs/tabs-adv.js

Answer (score 1):

```
var tabPanel = Ext.getCmp('tabsID');
var items = tabPanel.items.items;
tabPanel.add({
    title: tTitle,
    id: tChieldID,
    closable: true,
    layout: 'fit',
    flex: 1,
    items: [{...}]
});
tabPanel.setActiveTab(tChieldID);
```

Comment: It's great that you've used sample code in your answer, however, it would be helpful if you would provide a description with your code.